# I need to find a proof that b²≥4a(b-a) when both b and a are real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

The inequality can be right or wrong. If it's right then I have to find proof. If its wrong, I need a counterexample

Comment: have you tried to prove/disprove it?

Comment: @Nick  I've tried to prove it but idk how

Comment: Just rewrite all of them in left hand side. (hint)

Comment: Thanks guys found it

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Needless now, the O.P. found it. I really should reread before posting… Thanks for warning me!

Answer (score 3):

**Algebraic method**

$$b^2\geq 4a(b-a)$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow b^2-4a(b-a)\geq 0$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow (2a-b)^2\geq 0$$
which is true.

**Intuitive way**

Intuitively, if sum of two numbers is fixed, closer the numbers, higher the product. For example,
$$1×9=9$$
$$2×8=16$$
$$3×7=21$$
$$4×6=24$$
$$5×5=25$$
Now, observe that LHS is $b\times b$ and RHS is $2a\times (2b-2a)$, having sum $2b$ of multiplicands on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

$AM \ge GM$ gives $$4a^2+b^2 \ge 2 \sqrt{4a^2.b^2}=4ab$$ |where $a,b$ are real numbers. Hence proved.